# Read in C++ text file with multiple fields

Tags: c++

I have a text file like this

```
A: [[1, 95], [78, 110]],
B: [[85, 86], [88, 93], [96, 156], [158, 442]],
```

how can I read it in c++ and get a cout like

```
Period : A with ranges 1-95, 78-100
Period : B with ranges 85-86, 88-93, 96-156, 158-442
```

The main point is that each Period can have several ranges, but the first and the last are always starting with "[[" and end "]]," respectively.

Attempt:

```
ifstream ifs("temp");
string line;
float rang1, rang2,rang3;
while(std::getline(ifs, line))
{
    istringstream iss(line);
    string Per;
    iss >> Per >> rang1 >> rang2 >> rang3;

    cout<<"For Period ====="<<Per<<" range is "<<rang1 <<"  "<< rang2 <<" "<< rang3<<endl;
}
```

and that gives

```
For Period =====251168 range is 0  0  1.32513e-37
For Period =====251244 range is 0  0  1.32513e-37
For Period =====251251 range is 0  0  1.32513e-37
For Period =====251252 range is 0  0  1.32513e-37
```

Comment: Could you show us some code you attempted?

Comment: I ve tried something like

` ifstream ifs("temp");    
  string line;  
  
  float rang1, rang2,rang3;  
  while(std::getline(ifs, line))  
    {  
      fact=fact2=1;  
      istringstream iss(line);   
  
      string Per;  
      iss >> Per >> rang1 >> rang2 >> rang3;  
      } ` 

but I understand that I need to have maybe a vector for each of the Periods ?

PS - I ve been trying with no success to apply linebreakers in my reply - this http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks does not seem to work here ?

Comment: I really dont understand the negative voting - if you see something wrong, be polite enough to tell me what, not all of us are programming gurus!

Comment: Put the code in ur post!

Comment: it looks like a regex job.

Comment: @DavidHaim - any easy example ? thanks!

Comment: @jpw - ok, code edited with attempt and result

Comment: Well you can either use, the regex that is being recommended, or severely convoluted while loops on each and every line in the file. Involving substr(), find() using a variable to hold the index to not find the same thing again, and it will be useful in learning how strings manipulation is but overall... Just. Just look into the regex library man, don't even need to use boost anymore it's now a part of c++11 and onward.

Comment: google "split string by regex c++" and you're good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal code example assumes that the given file is never corrupted.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Range
{
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Range& p);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Range& p);

    int lower;
    int bigger;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Range& p)
{
    is.ignore(1, '[');
    std::string s;
    std::getline(is, s, ']');

    auto commaPos = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), ',');

    p.lower = std::stoi(std::string{s.begin(), commaPos});
    p.bigger = std::stoi(std::string{std::next(commaPos, 2), s.end()});

    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Range& p)
{
    return os << "[" << p.lower << ", " << p.bigger << "]";
}

struct Period
{
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Period& p);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Period& p);

    std::string name;
    std::vector<Range> ranges;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Period& p)
{
    std::getline(is, p.name, ':');

    is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '[');
    do
    {
        Range r;
        is >> r;
        p.ranges.push_back(r);
    } while(!(is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ').eof()));

    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Period& p)
{
    os << p.name << ": [";
    for(auto a = p.ranges.begin(); a != std::prev(p.ranges.end()); ++a)
        os << *a << ", ";
    os << *(std::prev(p.ranges.end())) << "],";

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<Period> periods;

    std::fstream inputFileStream("myinputfile", std::ios::in);
    for(std::string s; std::getline(inputFileStream, s); )
    {
        periods.push_back(Period());

        std::stringstream ss(s);
        ss >> periods.back();
    }

    for(const auto& a : periods)
    {
        std::cout << "Period : " << a.name << " with ranges ";
        for(auto b = a.ranges.begin(); b != std::prev(a.ranges.end()); ++b)
            std::cout << b->lower << "-" << b->bigger << ", ";
        auto last = std::prev(a.ranges.end());
        std::cout << last->lower << "-" << last->bigger << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can run this [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb3d69f2ea1e83fa)!
A lesser painful approach would be to use regexes. You can teach them to yourself by visting for example [regex101](http://regex101.com). To use regexes in C++ simply take a look at the corresponding standard [Regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)-Library, the examples should get you going.

Comment: how can I match `a.name`  to a certain string/number  ? ie
if I want to see if `std::string numb = std::to_string(a.name);` matches a certain pattern as "Period" can be a number as well ?

Comment: Period can be a number - so, how can I find if a certain number is one of the periods ? I tried to convert the number to be tested `std::string num = std::to_string(251244);` and then a `if (num==a.name) cout <<" Period matches number"<<endl;` but this does not work

Comment: Then it's not the number. `a.name` must contain `251244` as string if you set it like `a.name = std::to_string(251244)`

Comment: you define `std:string name` in your code which is ok - the question is why when I convert a given number `to_string` and then compare it with the string  `a.name` does not work

Comment: Because it is not equal, simple as that. I cannot make any assumptions without seeing your code.

Comment: ok - have a look here [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00ddd57d5849c2fc) l90 & l95

Comment: It "does not work" because it is simply not equal to it.
In `int main` I'm writing your example file, there you can see, that no period has the name `21422`. Change it so and it will work fine. E.g. replace `A` with `21422` in l76